# How can I have a gitlab runner start an Android emulator with a window on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: android, android-emulator, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Gitlab on my android project and have a set of Espresso tests which run on a mac server. Gitlab-runner is setup on this mac to run in Shell mode and it execute a script which at the beginning starts an emulator:

```
emulator -avd my_avd
```

The machine has a screen and you can watch the emulator starting and the tests running.

**I now have to switch to a Ubuntu server** (it's running 16.04 lts), and I can't start the emulator with a window anymore, at least not from the gitlab-runner. When executing:

```
emulator -avd my_avd
```

It prints the error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

It works from a terminal though, just not from the gitlab runner service. I've had to add the flag no-window to allow the emulator to be started from the gitlab runner but then some tests fail, so I really need the emulator window.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Exxecuting

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

before trying to run the emulator fixed it :)

Comment: Please try to provide more details in your answers, in case others come across them.